# Sound Error in Dell d420

Tags: audio

My Dell D420 ... when i connect with headphone... it's working... i hear all of the sound (system sound etc) but i plug out the headphone i can't hear from my laptop speaker... i made just one time with headphone... in the previous, speaker is working well...

Comment: clean out the headphone jacks

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your audio drivers.  If you can't download them, they may be located on your hard drive under C:\Dell or C:\Drivers etc.

Comment: no driver software at under C: and others... :(